# WebSockets and Application Proxy Connection Issues

Tags: proxy, websocket, burp

Does anyone have a websocket connection working with an application proxy (e.g. burp or zap)?

For example, I have a working version of jWebSockets with works perfectly on my local machine.

However, when I intercept with Burp or Zap the connection times out and I get no server response back.

I have increased the timeout settings on the server side but this does not make a difference.

I have also tried using the invisible proxy option.

Thank you.

Comment: I would be interested in this, too. I tried a similar setup like you with the Apache webserver and mod_proxy, but it was always stripping the _Upgrade_ header sabotaging the handshake between client and server. But I did some research and found some promising solutions. Unfortunately I hadn't had time yet to try any of them. I wrote an article on my blog about this: http://ontraindevelopment.blogspot.de/2012/06/potential-solutions-for-my-reverse.html

Answer (score 1):

There are very few tools that support web sockets right now as its really a completely new protocol.

The current version of ZAP (1.4.1) wont, but the next major version will: http://code.google.com/p/zaproxy/wiki/GSoC2012_WebSockets

If you can build ZAP from the trunk then it will support web sockets - build instructions here: http://code.google.com/p/zaproxy/wiki/Building

It will allow you to view web socket traffic, intercept and change it *and* fuzz it to try and find vulnerabilities.

Let us know if you have any problems with it, eg via the ZAP developer group: http://groups.google.com/group/zaproxy-develop

Simon (ZAP Project Lead).

Update - Web Sockets support in ZAP is now available in the weekly cross-platform releases, which can be downloaded from http://code.google.com/p/zaproxy/downloads/list so you dont have to build it yourself

Comment: And ZAP version 2.0.0 has now been released (same url as above) which includes WebSockets support.

Comment: Under Scientific Linux 6.7 (like CentOs), using ZAP 2.4.3 and java version "1.8.0_20-ea"
I have the same problem, how can I solve it ?